# Python OpenCV perspective transformation

Tags: python, opencv, perspective

I have an image with perspective and there is a corner of the table. Task: how can I correct perspective to see the viewed part of the table with corrected perspective, having only a coords of the corner and  directions of the edges of the table.

Thank you in advance.

EDIT:
For example I want to convert this picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZANZ.jpg
to something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdjCy.jpg

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What have you so far?

Comment: Can you upload pictures of your input image and a mockup of your desired image?